# MySql delete row and add it to another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not expert for mysql. I have database in MySql. When delete row in some table I want to add it with primary key in another table. I can do that simply before execute on delete query, get that primary key from table and insert it to another table from application level. But I want to do that from database level. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What does "do that from a database level" mean?

Comment: I mean trigger for that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are searching is creating a "BEFORE DELETE" "TRIGGER" with an "INSERT" statement. Google it and you will find how to do something like this.

Here's an example for you:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER `delete_personne`$$

CREATE TRIGGER `delete_personne` BEFORE DELETE on `personne`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO histo_personne SELECT OLD.initialespers,OLD.nompers,OLD.prenompers,OLD.datenaisspers,OLD.photopers,OLD.validepers,now();
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Source: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?99,140057,141249#msg-141249

Comment: Before you go the route of triggers consider a single transaction with two commands: an insert and a delete.

Comment: He asked for "database level" of it. One way is to create a SP for deleting the records, and the second way is to create a trigger for delete I think.